# How do you get text in emmet completions when writing JSX in IntelliJ?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, emmet

For example you can usually write

```
div.classname{text}
```

and it becomes

```
<div class='classname'>text</div>
```

this works in intellij if you only write `div.classname` but once you add `{text}` it cant expand the expression anymore.

Anyone know how to fix this or is there another character than {} thats used when writing JSX?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in 2017.3.4 - `div.classname{text}` is expanded to `<div class='classname'>text</div>` as expected. What IDEA build do you work with? Curly braces in Emmet JSX are supported since 2017.3 - see [WEB-28500](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28500)